Are iGPUs utilized in any way while using a discrete GPU? Could they? Should they?
Whenever I've seen die shots of CPUs that contain integrated GPUs, it seems that the GPU takes up a not-insignificant portion of the die.

(Source: AMD "Phoenix 2" die shot, purely an example)
If the user chose to install a dedicated GPU and the iGPU otherwise went unused, it seems like this is a large portion of the die going to waste.
In such a scenario, would it even be possible to instead utilize some of the iGPU's resources to aide with general processing? I understand GPU architecture and CPU architecture are very different, but is there any part of the CPU pipeline that could be offloaded onto the GPU? Could this result in any meaningful decrease in processing time? Would it even be worth the amount of engineering required to make such a scheme work?

I'm not familiar with AMD. Just older Intel up through P II. But the internal GPU should be connected to the registration station as a resource for microops in the re-order buffer. It's likely that it can be used while an external GPU is being used. However, like any other CPU operation requiring data from on-die cache, external local package cache, cache on other CPUs, or external memory systems managed by chipsets that could be in competition with an external GPU's requests. So there's always memory bottlenecks as an issue.

Both GPUs are connected to the system and can be usable. This is occasionally used for mobile devices that can power down the external GPU and use the more efficient iGPU to save power.
In terms of normal use on a desktop, it would be uncommon to use the iGPU since typically an external GPU is many times faster while power savings is not so critical.

I understand GPU architecture and CPU architecture are very different, but is there any part of the CPU pipeline that could be offloaded onto the GPU?

No. Ignoring the differences in architecture, consider that pipeline stages have delays measured in picoseconds while accessing the GPU can take microseconds. The best you can do is run one program on the CPU and another program on the GPU(s).
